# Does a creature with blindsight have disadvantage on attack rolls while under effect of blindness spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, blind

### Premise

Casting [*blindness-deafness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blindness-deafness) on a creature with [blindsight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/monsters#Blindsight):

> A monster with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight, within a specific radius.

[blinded condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded):

> Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.

### Question

Do attack rolls have advantage against a creature with blindsight that has been blinded?

Comment: Honestly this isn't a duplicate to the question linked to it. The question linked to it was whether one with the blindsight condition could be blinded. This question assumes the answer to that is yes, and under such a case, asks if a specific consequence of blindness applies. They are two different questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically yes, since nothing about Blindsight says that it prevents the creature from being blinded. (And in some situations it might make sense, when a creature's blindsight is a secondary sense instead of their primary one).

In practice, all the examples of creatures I can find that have the Blindsight special ability are also explicitly immune to the Blindness condition (in the "Condition Immunities" block), so for those being Blinded will not bother them one bit.